# How to install MuleSoft in RHEL 7?

Tags: mule

Can anyone please summarize, how to install mulesoft runtime on RHEL step by step process ?
Suppose I have download tar file and extracted them , for running I have used under bin `./mule` . Is this enough or I need to configure any additional datas etc ? How to archive this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the step for Mule 3.5.2, this can be used for other mule version too -

1. Steps -
2. Login to RHEL server.
3. Copy mmc-distribution-mule-console-bundle-3.5.2-HF1.tar.gz (downloaded from Mulesoft support portal) to /data/mule folder.
   (In case of production setup, this file can be copied from Mule staging server from /home/ directory)
4. Go to /data/mule directory
5. Unzip mmc-distribution-mule-console-bundle-3.5.2-HF1.tar.gz using the following command
   gunzip mmc-distribution-mule-console-bundle-3.5.2-HF1.tar.gz
6. Extract mmc-distribution-mule-console-bundle-3.5.2-HF1.tar using the following command
   tar -xvf mmc-distribution-mule-console-bundle-3.5.2-HF1.tar
7. Move mule-enterprise-3.5.2 folder from mmc-distribution-mule-console-bundle-3.5.2-HF1 to the current directory ( /data/mule ) using the command
   mv mmc-distribution-mule-console-bundle-3.5.2-HF1/mule-enterprise-3.5.2/ /data/mule
8. Delete the folder mmc-distribution-mule-console-bundle-3.5.2-HF1, as the remaining contents (MMC and other scripts) are not needed
   rm -rf mmc-distribution-mule-console-bundle-3.5.2-HF1
9. Delete mmc-distribution-mule-console-bundle-3.5.2-HF1.tar file
   rm mmc-distribution-mule-console-bundle-3.5.2-HF1.tar
10. Create a soft link /data/mule/mule-enterprise to point to /data/mule/mule-enterprise-3.5.2 using the following command. 
    ln -s mule-enterprise-3.5.2 mule-enterprise
11. Go to /home/ directory and change MULE_HOME environment variable in /home/.bash_profile, from /data/mule/mule-enterprise-3.5.0 to /data/mule/mule-enterprise
12. Execute the following command  (from /home/ directory)for having the latest value for MULE_HOME in the current context
    source .bash_profile
13. Go to $MULE_HOME ( /data/mule/mule-enterprise ) and delete .mule folder 
    rm –rf .mule

Installing Enterprise Licence

1. Steps -
2. Copy the license file mule-ee-license.lic to $MULE_HOME/bin directory
3. Go to $MULE_HOME/bin  and run the following command to install license
   mule -installLicense mule-ee-license.lic
4. Mule removes the trial license and replaces it with the enterprise edition license.  In the $MULE_HOME/conf directory, Mule saves a new file called muleLicenseKey.lic
5. To verify that Mule successfully installed your Enterprise license, run the following command
   mule –verifyLicense
   If the licence installation is successful, the following text is displayed in the output.
   Valid license key --> Evaluation = false, Expiration Date = Wed Dec 31 00:00:00 GMT 2014, Contact Name = Sanjeet Pandey, Contact Email Address = sanjeetkumarpandey@gmail.com, Contact Telephone = 07831792088, Contact Company = PERSONAL, Contact Country = UK, Entitlements = clustering,datamapper

Answer (score 1):

please follow this link for step by step guide:

http://intrgrex.com/installing-mule-as-a-service-on-linux/